# Magento 2.2.3 on Cen0s7 (mail server)

Tags: magento2.2.3, send-mail

I had Magento running on a shared server (hostgater) till I found out that I did not have root access and could not change the php level and various other things. So i cancled my hosting, bought a server and now... I am running Magento 2.2.3 on a fully updated Centos7 in a VM in esxi. (yes I am an IT guy) So my question is what is the best way to set up a mail server with Magento. I think i read somewhere that magento uses php for mail. If that is the case would sendmail be the best option? So my main goal is to have the email come from example@mydomain.com. I am pretty sure that the mail server would have to be installed on the same os and vm as magento correct?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would setup mailgun or sendgrid to send all emails as not only will you ensure your servers IP won't be blacklisted you can also have logs on your emails

Comment: Thanks. do you have to add an add-on to make this work in magneto?

Comment: github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp/blob/master/README.md this will enable you to use mailgun smtp services for example or there are other extensions out there for mailgun which use the API

Comment: is there an option that i would be able to use indipendant email address as configured in magento like sales @... contact us @ .... It looks like the plugin that you suggested uses only on email.